# opening filename containing Unicode characters in VC6 compiler

Tags: c++, unicode, visual-c++-6

We have a maintainance project that was build on VC6 compilers. At some part of the code we have a file open function using ifstream.open() method which fails when the filename contains UNICODE characters like chinese characters. Since VC6 compiler doesn't support the wchar_t* version of open function, is there a way i can open this type of file? i tried FILE* _wfopen method too but it fails too.

Thanks in advance

As per RemyLebeau's guidance - i tried using errno,i got the value as 22 which indicates invalid parameter. Plese see my code 
    std::wstring filename=_wgetenv(L"IVT_FILENAME");
    FILE * stream;
    stream=_wfopen(filename.c_str(),L"r");

This works perfectly fine in vc9 and file opens and im able to read contents. Don't know why it doesnt work in vc6. The value of stream is NULL

Comment: Declare it a limitation and move on.

Comment: Visual Studio 6.0 supported `_wfopen`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa246392(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: It does support _wfopen but it fails to open the filename containing unicode characters and returns null for FILE* object. GetLastError returns the code 123- filename not found. When the same code i copy paste to visual studio 8.0, it passes without any problems

Comment: If `_wfopen()` fails and says the file was not found, then either the file really was not found (more likely) or `_wfopen()` itself has a bug (less likely). Double check your input Unicode data to make sure it is correct. BTW, if you [read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx), `_wfopen()` does not use `GetLastError()` for error reporting, it uses [`errno`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3ayayh1.aspx) instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I did check the existence of the file.The file is very much present.
Moreover when i copy paste the same code to VC9, the file is opened without any problem. SO i suspect this has to do something with VC6.

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem was with _wgetenv function. It doesnot work properly in VC6 compiler. Replacing it with GetEnvironmentVariable solves the issue and file is opened

Comment: How could the debugger not show you this?  I doubt you found the real problem, having to maintain both getenv() and _wgetenv() is a tricky problem.  Using GetEnvironmentVariable is a workaround for a corrupted 8-bit copy of the environment.